# Parsing migration script

Tags: c#, parsing, migration

I have an input text file which has the following details:

```
object network Name_Personal_1  
subnet 121.224.210.111 255.255.255.224  
object network Name_Personal_07  
subnet 101.112.22.0 255.255.255.111  
object network NameAA_1  
subnet 101.16.12.11 255.255.255.111

object-group network Name_Personal  
network-object 303.113.103.11 255.255.255.111  
network-object 400.115.104.11 255.255.255.111  
network-object 590.114.106.11 255.255.255.111  
network-object 600.116.107.11 255.255.255.111  
network-object 700.117.108.11 255.255.255.111  
network-object object Name_Personal_1  
network-object object Name_Personal_07

object-group network NameAA  
network-object object NameAA_1

object-group network NameBB  
network-object 500.13.500.64 255.255.255.111  
network-object 100.11.111.0 255.255.255.111  
network-object 300.11.111.0 255.255.255.111
```

Now what i need to do is Store the name, IP Address, subnet mask and group name

For example Name_Personal_1 has the following details:

```
Name: Name_Personal_1  
Ip: 121.224.210.111  
Subnet: 255.255.255.001  
Group: Name_Personal
```

What I can't find how to do is that if for example Name_Personal has a network-object

```
120.11.1.139.64 255.255.255.111
```

I need to find the last time before that line there was object-group network (name) and take the name in this case for example Name_Personal so I put it in the Group: attribute. The next time if for example i want

```
100.11.111.0 255.255.255.111
```

which is under the object-group network NameBB then i have to find what group it is in by finding the last time there was an object-group network before it is read so i can get the NameBB name in this case.

It is important to tell you that i am getting this file read line by line from a text file which i am reading with a streamreader

```
StreamReader  file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\my.name\desktop\input.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{ 
     if (line.Contains("network_object"))
     {
          Network n = new Network();
          n.Name = ""; 
          n.IPAddress = "";
          n.SubnetMask = "";
          n.GroupName = "";    
     }
}
```

all I have is a main class and a network class containing name IP, subnet and group strings and I also need to read each line not enter the IP myself so the program needs to get the name of the group under which each IP and subnet fall. So the application would go trough each line and then when it meats a network-object it searches above for the name (object-group network(name)).

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear if you want to serialize the file into memory, or just search for the network group. Based on this:

> which is under the object-group network NameBB then i have to find
>   what group it is in by finding the last time there was an object-group
>   network before it is read so i can get the NameBB name in this case.

I'm assuming you just want to grab the `object network` or `object-group network` preceding the IP.

```
public string GetNetworkNameForIp(String ip)
{
    String currentNetworkName = null;
    using (var file = new StreamReader(@"input.txt"))
    {
        const string object_group_network = "object-group network ";
        const string object_network = "object network ";
        string line;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith(object_group_network))
                currentNetworkName = line.Substring(object_group_network.Length);
            if (line.StartsWith(object_network))
                currentNetworkName = line.Substring(object_network.Length);

            if (line.Contains(ip))
                return currentNetworkName;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Testing:

```
GetNetworkNameForIp("100.11.111.0")
```

Returns "NameBB"

```
GetNetworkNameForIp("121.224.210.111")
```

Returns "Name_Personal_1"

If you want to de-serialize it, then you can expand upon this method to parse the details (as it's storing the last `object-group network`/`object network` it sees - you can easily add some logic to fill in the properties)

Comment: It is very near to what i want, but the difference is Name_Personal_1 is a name of an ip and the Name_BB is a group so what i need if the program finds object_network it searches for the name after network-object group as above for 100.11.111.0 i need to get a return of NameBB as you indicated but i see a paramter string ip but in reality i won't enter anything i just have to read the file and do the search nearly as you did but  without entering any details myself to search for, btw thanks fore trying to help :)

Comment: in reality i want to grab also the ip and subnet and insert them in the object which i created that holds Name: IP: Subnet: Group: (the group which that particular name is in) that's why i can't input the ip myself. the object network or object-group network  are used to help with getting the details i need.